# With the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation prove the following equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $F=F(z,p):\Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ be smooth and independent of $x\in\Omega$. Let $u$ be a solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation of $\mathcal{F}(u)= \int_\Omega F(u,Du)dx$. I'd like to show that $\sum_i (\partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_j}u-F \delta_{i,j})_{x_i}=0$.

Since $u$ is a solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation and we've defined the Euler-Lagrange operator $L_F(u)=-\sum_i \partial_i (\partial_{p_i}F + \partial_zF)$ it follows that $L_F(u)=0$. I've been told that one should simply transform and compute the left side of the equation to prove that it equals $0$. I tried to transform the equation in order to use the fact that $u$ is a solution of the ELE of $\mathcal{F}(u)$. We have

$\sum_i (\partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_j}u-F \delta_{i,j})_{x_i} \\
= \sum_i \partial_{x_i}(\partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_j}u-F \delta_{i,j}) \\
= \sum_i \partial_{x_i}(\partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_j}u) - \sum_i \partial_{x_i}F \delta_{i,j} \\
= \sum_i \partial_{x_i}(\partial_{p_i}F) \partial_{x_j}u + \sum_i \partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_i}( \partial_{x_j}u) -\partial_{x_j}F \; \mathrm{(product \, rule)} \\
= \sum_i div(\partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_j}u) - \sum_i \partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_i} (\partial_{x_j}u) + \sum_i \partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_i}( \partial_{x_j}u) -\partial_{x_j}F \; \mathrm{(chain \, rule \, for \, divergence)}\\
= \sum_i div(\partial_{p_i}F \partial_{x_j}u) -\partial_{x_j}F.$

But I don't see how I can transform this expression any further or how I could use that $u$ is a solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation. I would appreciate if someone could give me tips so that I will be able to prove this assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: One has to distinguish between explicit $x$-derivatives $\partial_{x^i}$ and total $x$-derivatives $$d_{x^i}~=~\partial_{x^i} +~ d_{x^j}u ~\partial_{z}+d_{x^j}\partial_{x^i}u~\partial_{p_i}\tag{0}.$$ No explicit $x$-dependence 
$$ \partial_{x^i}F~=~0 \tag{1}$$
of the Lagrangian $F$ leads (via [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)) to the on-shell continuum equations for the energy-momentum tensor:
$$\begin{align}
 (\partial_{p_i}F ~\partial_{x^j}u - F \delta_i^j)_{x^i} 
&~~~=~  d_{x^i}(\partial_{p_i}F ~\partial_{x^j}u - F \delta_i^j) \cr
&~~~=~  d_{x^i}\partial_{p_i}F~ \partial_{x^j}u 
+ \partial_{p_i}F~d_{x^i}\partial_{x^j}u - d_{x^j}F   \cr
&~~~\stackrel{(0)}{=}~  d_{x^i}\partial_{p_i}F~ \partial_{x^j}u 
+ \partial_{p_i}F~\partial_{x^i}\partial_{x^j}u \cr
&~~~-~ (\partial_{x^i}F +\partial_{z}F~ d_{x^j}u +\partial_{p_i}F~d_{x^j}\partial_{x^i}u)~\cr
&\stackrel{(1)+(3)}{=}~0. 
\end{align}\tag{2}$$
The last equality follows from eq. (1) and the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
$$ d_{x^i}\partial_{p_i}F~=~\partial_{z}F.\tag{3}$$
The word *on-shell* here means that the EL eq. (3) is satisfied. It is implicitly understood in eq. (2) that the Lagrangian $F$ is applied $F(u,\partial u)$ to a solution $u$ of the  EL eq. (3). In contrast, the  Lagrangian $F$ in eq. (1) is *not* applied to a solution $u$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've got another question regarding your answer: Do we get in the last equation $d_{x^j}F=\partial_zF d_{x^j}u+\partial_{p_i}F d_{x^j} \partial_{x^i}u$ because the Lagrangian $F$ is independent of $x$ and therefore $\partial_{x^j}F=0$? I thought the Lagrangian $F(u,Du)$ was still dependent, even if not explicitly, on $x$, because $u$ and $Du$ are dependent on $x$ and then the partial derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $x^j$ wouldn't be $0$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: $\uparrow$ You are right, not mistaken.

Comment: But how do we get this equation? With the Noether Theorem? Then I still have to check that $F$ is infinitesimal invariant. Is this correct?

Comment: So x-independence is equivalent to $\partial_{x^i}F=0$? I thought this wasn't true. I'm sorry but I'd like to understand every detail and I still don't completely understand this.

Comment: Explicit $x$-independence (1) is an assumption.

Comment: This I know. But what isn't clear to me is: is $x$-independence equivalent to $(1)$?

Comment: Are you talking about total or explicit $x$-independence?

Comment: By $x$-independent I mean that $x$ isn't explicitly in $F$, we don't have the form $F(x,u,Du)$. But since here $F$ is of the form $F(u(x),Du(x))$ and $u$ and $Du$ are dependent of $x$ I don't see why $(1)$ is equivalent to the assumption.

Comment: It seems you are talking about total $x$-independence.

Comment: Do you have a link or do you know where I can look up the two definitions of the idependence you are talking about? Because I've never heard about those two independences and how they are defined and therefore I'm not able to understand your hints.